# how can i get 5 inputs at a time and add them the my array

Tags: c

desired output!

Enter the bomb positions in sets of 5 where a value

of 1=BOMB, and 0=NO BOMB. Space-delimit your input.

(Example: 1 0 0 1 1) NOTE: there are 35 to set! // is an user inputted number which has to a a multiple of 5

Positions [ 1- 5]: 0 0 0 0 1

Positions [ 6-10]: 1 0 0 1 1

Positions [11-15]: 1 0 1 1 1

Positions [16-20]: 0 1 0 0 0

Positions [21-25]: 1 0 1 0 0

Positions [26-30]: 0 0 0 1 0

Positions [31-35]: 1 0 1 0 1

I have to add the inputs to an array

my code:

```
printf("BOMB Placement\n");
printf("--------------\n");
printf("Enter the bomb positions in sets of %d where a value\n", MULTIPLE);
printf("of 1=BOMB, and 0=NO BOMB. Space-delimit your input.\n");
printf("(Example: 1 0 0 1 1) NOTE: there are %d to set!\n", game.path_length);

int i = 0, j = 0;                                   //for setting bomb locations
for (i = 0; i < game.path_length; i += 5){
    printf("   Positions [%2.1d-%2.1d]: ", i+1, i+5);
    for ( j = 0; j < game.path_length; j++) {       //game.path_length is user inputted
        scanf("%d", &game.bomb_locations[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I cant seem to get 5 of them at a time like the outputs!

Comment: What is `game.path_length` and what is the exact value it is set to? What does "can't seem to get 5" mean exactly - what incorrect behaviour is observed? Please provide complete code as a [mre] as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Seems `for ( j = 0; j < game.path_length; j++)` should be `for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++)`

Comment: Ahmed Kursi, Error handling much easier if your read a _line_ of input into a string and then parse the string for 5 `int`.  Read with `fgets()` and drop using `scanf()`.

Comment: @kaylum That will result in `game.bomb_locations` overwriting previous input with future input in the line `scanf("%d", &game.bomb_locations[j]);`. He should most likely rewrite his inner loop to `for(int j = 0; j < game.path_length; ++j)` (note the `int`) and, outside both loops, have `int index = 0;` with `scanf("%d", &game.bomb_locations[index++]);` Alternatively, he can compute the index based on the value of `i` and `j`.

Comment: @user904963 Good point. I didn't look closely enough but just saw that didn't look right.

Answer (score -2):

Seems all you have to do is change the `for j` loop and manage the multiple value `scanf()`;
The way your `for j` loop is right now it iterates the whole gamepath every 5 positions that the `i` avances.

```
for (i = 0; i < game.path_length; i += 5){
    printf("   Positions [%2.1d-%2.1d]: ", i+1, i+5);

    int b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &b1, &b2, &b3, &b4, &b5);
    
    game.bomb_locations[i] = b1;
    game.bomb_locations[i+1] = b2;
    game.bomb_locations[i+2] = b3;
    game.bomb_locations[i+3] = b4;
    game.bomb_locations[i+4] = b5;

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: If the other post has a valid answer then just mark it as a duplicate. Also, this doesn't directly address the problems in the OP's code.

Comment: `while (scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &b1, &b2, &b3, &b4, &b5) != 5)` will become an infinete loop if any of the input values are not ints. And why scan into intermediate variables instead of directly into `bomb_locations`?

Comment: If any of the input values are not ints, specifically 1=BOMB, and 0=NO BOMB as stated by Ahmed, there will be bugs down the line, better catch them at the begining.

The intermediate variables are for visual purposes only, instead of a huge line `scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &game.bomb_locations[i], &game.bomb_locations[i+1], &game.bomb_locations[i+2], &game.bomb_locations[i+3], &game.bomb_locations[i+4])`

Comment: "*better catch them at the begining*". Agreed. But putting in a possible infinete loop is not the way to catch it. Just use an `if` rather than a loop.

Comment: There, removed the `do-while` as the question was to handle 5 inputs in one `scanf` anyway, not handle any possible input error.